# SQL Update & INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update a specific column in my DB (Using MSSQL)

I have wrote a query to return the values already, but the problem I can't update the other table with the generated values from (More than one row) I tried using a variable to declare them and then update the table, but the problem it returns more than one value, so I wonder how may I update the table using these values.

My Select query:

```
SELECT SUM(_Items.MagParam1) + SUM(_Items.MagParam2) AS Test11 
FROM _Char 
INNER JOIN _Inventory 
    ON _Char.CharID = _Inventory.CharID
INNER JOIN _Items 
    ON _Inventory.ItemID = _Items.ID64 
 WHERE _Inventory.Slot BETWEEN 1 AND 13  AND _Inventory.ItemID > 0
GROUP BY [_Char].[CharName16],[_Char].[CurLevel],[_Char].[CharID]
```

So this query returns a value for every CharID I have, I want to update all rows in _Char with it's generated value from the previous query.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CharId` is unique, I would do something like this:

```
update c
    ? = cc.test11  -- ? is the column to be updated
    from _Char c JOIN
         (SELECT c.CharID, SUM(i.MagParam1) + SUM(i.MagParam2) AS Test11 
          FROM _Char c INNER JOIN
               _Inventory i
              ON c.CharID = i.CharID INNER JOIN
              _Items it
              ON i.ItemID = it.ID64 
          WHERE i.Slot BETWEEN 1 AND 13  AND i.ItemID > 0
          GROUP BY c.CharID
         ) cc
         ON c.CharID = cc.CharID;
```

If you require all three columns (`CharName16`, `CurLevel` and `CharID`) to define a unique row, then include them in the `SELECT`, `GROUP BY`, and `ON` clauses.

Comment: Nope, I only need the CharID. However, trying to run that query.

Comment: Worked like a charm, you saved me... Thank you so much <3